Why can't I send out my solana from phantom
When I attempt to do so it says something along the lines of unable to send or failed also transaction failed during simulation
My wallet is EYsJVQU5igQNaNMptsyL2A6h6QWso34MYxTriAkdQqWj
I am not sure why this issue came up or how I can resolve it but I believe there should be a way to fix this.

You must have interacted with a compromised dApp and signed an instruction that transferred the authority of your account to this address nonkuCfa2QHS1WZkUrFb7ftYg1mgbyZEk37trQgB1Ax
Your wallet address should be owned by the System Program which allows you to make send and sign transactions.

Is there any way to go against this i.e like signing to a new account

This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - From Review
